# Exchange Hybrid Intermittently giving NDRs

Tags: exchange, exchange-hybrid, connector, ndr, microsoft-dfo365

New year, looks like a pretty active site.  My company has a Hybrid config in place that cannot be removed at the moment.  Since the 22/04 we have been having problems that certain domains intermittently fail with NDR.  The NDR is due to a hop timeout as it seems to be bouncing between on-prem and Exchange.  I have been speaking with other techs who say they have customers with similar problems since this date and I am checking to see if it's bigger than my problem.  So hard to troubleshoot as it is intermittent.  Thanks guys

Comment: How is your issue going now?

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue occur to internal users or external users? users on premise or users on exchange online?

Could you provide more details of NDRs for further troubleshooting? What is the specific generate sever for these NDR?

What can you see when you run [get-messagetrace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetrace?view=exchange-ps)?